# How to run Valgrind on my program in C?

Tags: valgrind

How do I use Valgrind utility with my simple C program in Linux?

Suppose my executable is `a.out`. How to check any leaks in my program with Valgrind.

I basically want to know how to use Valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
```

if your `a.out` is in the current working directory.

In case you have got Valgrind already installed you can learn about the usage running:

```
$ valgrind --help.
```

Unfortunately, there is no entry manual entry for Valgrind when running `man valgrind`.

Comment: tried valgrind ./.aout, but its not working. Do I have to install any packages to get this running?? it says :-bash: valgrind: command not found

Comment: Well that sounds like valgrind is not yet installed
Install it with `sudo apt-get install valgrind` on ubuntu